# Horizontal Scrollbar Styling in CSS using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been hunting around for something to achieve custom stylable horizontal scrollbars. I've found two things that seem to do it but both are hugely complex and large in size, and both have problems for me.

First, FleXcroll is full of bugs and doesn't work very well for me, for some reason.
Second, tonylea horizontal scrollbars, this needs the elements to be wrapped in ULs and LIs where the system it needs to apply to is nested divs, with sibling divs to contain each element that needs to be scrolled.

Has anyone got any idea of how to style a scrollbar without huge jQuery plugins?

Is there any simple, compiled plugin that is flexible enough to work with varying HTML structures?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One is [nanoscroll](http://jamesflorentino.com/jquery.nanoscroller/)

```
$(selector).nanoScroller();
```

and one more is [slimscroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll)

```
//for SlimScroll
$(selector).slimScroll({
  width: '300px',
  height: '500px',
  size: '10px',
  position: 'left'
});
```

Comment: Hi, neither of these seem to apply to horizontal scrolling... :(

Comment: http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/
try this it has the property like :
`$('#scrollbar2').tinyscrollbar({ axis: 'x'});`

Comment: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/
`$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();`
this has both the property of **horizontal** as well as **vertical** scrolling